# 99 Chevy Venture leaking water

Tags: chevrolet, cooling-system, radiator, leak

When I put water in the radiator it flows out as quick as I pour it in. The reservoir is also empty. What is possibly the problem?

Comment: The very first thing we'd need to know to help is where the water is coming out from. Can you look around and see if you can tell? Maybe get someone to help so you can look under the car and around the engine compartment until you have at least a general area.

Comment: When you say it "flows out" what do you mean?  Out of the radiator?  Out of the engine and ending up on the floor?  If the system is really depleted coolant will need to fill the engine block and hoses as well as the radiator.  The owners manual will usually give a total coolant capacity.  If you have to add more than that to fill the system it is leaking somewhere.  Given the age a damaged hose or engine block would be my first guess.

Answer (score 1):

If water is coming out as quickly as you are pouring it in, you have a major leak. Look under the van, find where it's coming from.

Likely candidates for a leak this big are:

- radiator drain plug. Located at the bottom of the radiator (driver side, if I'm not mistaken), it may be open or defective.
- one of your radiator hoses, likely the lower one. Squeeze it to look for cracks, make sure it is snug at both ends.
- could be a hole in the radiator. Remove the cooling fans to have visual access to the back of the radiator.

Comment: Or, if you live somewhere cold, it could be that a freeze plug has come out. Maybe even if you don't live somewhere cold.